# create Linux Pidfile

Tags: linux, daemon

the os is Centos7

how can create a pidfile via command?

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
#cmd to createin /var/run/example/
daemon --user $USER --pidfile $pidfile "$DAEMON" start
```

but the pid was not created.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`--pidfile` is used to check wether the daemon process is already running. On RHEL (and derivates) the daemon function won't write the pidfile.

You can not use `$!` with daemon to get the pid as well. So you have to do the following command to get the pid from the list of process

`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep YOUR_PROCESS_NAME | awk '{ print $2 }' > pidfile`

if you want to use daemon.

You can also use another tool such as [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize) which will make the pid file.

Comment: So I must write it by myself?  I am not familiar with Linux, is there any command can create this file ?

Comment: @user3644708 yes since you can't use `$!` which is why i never use the daemon program and write my own daemons.